# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException in Button

Tags: ios, swift, exception, nsexception

I'm creating a simple Tic Tac Toe game in [swift](/questions/tagged/swift).

My `playAgain` button causes an `uncaught exception`, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
var buttonToClear : UIButton
for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
    buttonToClear = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
    buttonToClear.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
}
```

Error :

```
-[TicTacToe.ViewController playAgainButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TicTacToe.ViewController playAgainButton:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

First throw call stack: -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
```

Comment: Read the error message. It clearly says what is going wrong, and your code has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

In Interface builder, click on playAgainButton, then click connections inspector button on the right tabbar (it is the right most button). Now look under Sent Events, you will see unwanted connection(s) to outdated functions here, remove them to fix the problem.

If above is not the case, you probably have an unwanted call in your code on button tap.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defined the body of **playAgainButton** method in `TicTacToe` `ViewController`.

So please do it

```
@IBAction func playAgainButton(sender: UIButton) {
    // do your stuff over here
  }
```